# Múltiples archivos y plantillas .ejs en index

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

estoy teniendo el siguiente problema y voy a tratar de detallarlo lo mejor posible=>
Estoy listando desde mongoDB (con exito aclaro) la informacion de mi base de datos en la ruta /categorias.
El poblema esta cuando en lugar de listarlo en /categorias lo quiero incluir en el index (/) para listarlo ahi.

El error que recibo es
ERROR QUE RECIBO ES

**arrayCategorias is not defined**

Asi lo tengo (aca esta mi problema al hacer include('categorias') )=>

index.ejs

```html
<%- include('template/cabecera', {tituloWeb: "Pagina de inicio"}) -%>
    <h1>Titulo de mi index con EJS</h1>
    <h2><%= titulo %></h2>

    <%- include('categorias') -%>

    
    <%- include('template/footer') -%>
```

categoria.ejs

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<% if (arrayCategorias.length > 0) { %>
    <% arrayCategorias.forEach(categoria => { %>

      <div class="col">
        <%= categoria.nombre %>
      </div>
  
  <% }) %>
  <% } %>

</div>
</div>
```

aca las rutas

rutasWeb.js

```html
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { 
        titulo: 'Index'
    });
});
```

este es el pedido en la base de datos que aclaro que cuando lo cargo en **/categorias** funciona bien

categorias.js

```html
const express = require ("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Categoria = require("../models/categorias.js");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const arrayCategoriaDB = await Categoria.find();
        res.render('categorias',{
            arrayCategorias: arrayCategoriaDB
                    })
    } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
    }
        });
```

por ultimo app.js

```html
//motor de plantillas
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/view');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use("/", require('./router/rutasWeb'));
app.use("/productos", require('./router/productos'));
app.use("/categorias", require('./router/categorias'));
```

y el ERROR QUE RECIBO ES

**arrayCategorias is not defined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `rutasWeb.js`, cuando renderizas la vista de `index`, no estás pasando a la vista el `arrayCategorias`, por lo que es obvio que no va a estar definido cuando llames a `<%- include('categorias') %>` . La vista de categorías te funciona porque le estás pasando ese array, si lo quieres incluir en el index, también tienes que pasárselo al index.

En `rutasWeb.js` realiza las siguientes modificaciones:

```
const Categoria = require("../models/categorias.js");
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const arrayCategoriaDB = await Categoria.find();

        res.render('index', { 
        titulo: 'Index',
        arrayCategorias: arrayCategoriaDB
         });
      } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Y en la vista index ejs:

```
<%- include('template/cabecera', {tituloWeb: "Pagina de inicio"}) -%>
    <h1>Titulo de mi index con EJS</h1>
    <h2><%= titulo %></h2>

    <%- include('categorias',{arrayCategorias}) %>

    
    <%- include('template/footer') -%>
```

Comment: Posta GRACIAS! me super sirvio, gracias de verdad por la explicación y el ejemplo